# Java ArrayList: Difference between Copy Constructor and Copying via assignment

Tags: java, list

I have two lists, `ListA` and `ListB` and I want to copy `ListB` to `ListA`.

What is the difference between the following, in terms of complexity and result:

1. `ListA = ListB;`
2. `ListA = new ArrayList(ListB);`

Comment: 1) copies the reference to a List 2) creates a new list with a copy of the references to the elements in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `listA = listB`, there is only one list. So if you call `listA.add(something);`, it will add to `listB` too.

With `listA = new ArrayList(listB);` there are two lists (which happen to contain the same objects). So if you call `listA.add(something);`, it will NOT add anything to `listB`.

In terms of complexity, the first one is a simple assignement (i.e. runs in constant time), whereas the second runs in O(n), n being the size of `listB`.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case there is no copying at all. Just **aliasing**: `listA` can be viewed as a synonym, alias for `ListB`.

This is, naturally, due to Java's exclusive usage of **reference types**. No type in Java can actually hold an object as its value.

Answer (score 3):

for `ListA = ListB`

You are not copying the list, you are just assigning another alias (reference) to that object.